# How to show log in debug mode only for iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, debugging, logging, nslog

I am debugging the application in iPhone Simulator.I want to show log only when the application is running in debug mode in iPhone Simulator.I am using the `NSLog`. How can I put the condition for `NSLog` so that the logs should be printed on console in debug mode only?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this in your `.pch` file:

```
#ifndef DLog
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(_format_, ...) NSLog(_format_, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DLog(_format_, ...)
#endif
#endif
```

Now you can use `DLog` instead of `NSLog` for all log messages that should only be printed in your debug builds.

One could also redefine `NSLog` but there sometimes are log messages that you do want to appear in the device logs (like critical error messages).

See also [The Evolution of a Replacement for NSLog](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog) for ideas on how to improve the debug log macro.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"Your log statement");
#endif
```